# macOS web browser based on Chrome/Chromium that does not auto-update in background?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, software-update, web-browser, web-browsing

On my new M1 system I've decided to switch to the desktop Safari browser for battery, privacy, and security reasons.

However, many websites are designed for Chrome/Chromium and it would be good to have a standalone browser available for such cases.

I would like to avoid installing vanilla Google Chrome due to the ["Chrome is Bad"](https://chromeisbad.com) issue and the `keystone` background daemon process aggressively using CPU and memory even when Chrome is closed.

- [Brave](https://brave.com) has a still-open issue requesting this from 2019. Based on the devs' responses it seems antithetical to their app.

  - [The option to turn ON / OFF Automatic Updates. Please](https://community.brave.com/t/the-option-to-turn-on-off-automatic-updates-please/194718)
  - [Add a "Disable autoupdate" feature (disable updates)](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/5576)
- [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) seems to install a `Microsoft AutoUpdate` background daemon similar to Chrome's.

  - [Can I disable the (intrusive) Microsoft AutoUpdate in Edge?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/can-i-disable-the-intrusive-microsoft-autoupdate/1d51c81c-4ba8-4c26-b149-79b97cc4a900)
  - [New Update Experience for Mac available in Edge Beta](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/new-update-experience-for-mac-available-in-edge-beta-dev-canary/m-p/2200983)

It's ok if the browser "checks for updates" on launch (in a manner similar to the [Sparkle framework](https://sparkle-project.org)). What I want to avoid is an always-running background daemon doing who-knows-what to my system, like Chrome's `keystone` updater does.

Turning off auto-updates is also a needed feature on metered/limited cellular or satellite internet connections.

Are there any shipping consumer macOS Chromium-based desktop web browsers that are self-contained, without an always-running resource-hogging update mechanism?

Comment: Not a direct answer but the process in question can be blocked from internet access using Firewall

Comment: The link you posted (to chromeisbad.com) has some suggestions you didn't mention:
"If you need a Chromium-based browser, try Brave, Opera, or Vivaldi."